# Two submit buttons - perform cgi on second

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on a form that allows the user to edit, add, and remove committees. In the edit section, I wrote php code that allows the user to select (from a drop down populated by a csv) the name of the committee and then, when a first submit is clicked, information about that committee automatically displays in the fields of the form.

The problem is that I need cgi action linked to a second submit button at the end of the form, so that once it is clicked, all of the information will be updated. This is the button that actually needs to send in the data. The previous submit button was so the php could get the value of the selected committee and the info about it. The php-autofill feature is to (hopefully) make life easier for the user. The php is very intertwined with the html so having a separate file would be tricky.

My question: can I have two submit buttons in one form if the form has action="something.cgi" and only the second button is supposed to do the action?

Comment: What i would do is give each of the submits a name/value and then based on the values determin which submit was pressed and then do what needs to be done from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either (A) Use two separate forms with separate `action`'s, or (B) Write a JS handler for the second button to post to a different URL